# Display two field in forms by reactnative

Tags: ios, forms, react-native

Please Help i want to dipslay two field in forms first field about country 
 second about city of country  the condition second field display after selection in first field for example if i have a field about country when  i choose america another field display all the city for america ?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes but i haven't a result